# How to use Mockito for composite object

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, junit4

I want to mock a DAO manager which is something like this

```
public class DaoManager{
  @Autowired
   private Service1 service;
   @Autowired
   private Service2  service 2;
   @Autowired
   private DAOManager1 manager 1;

   public CustomerDetail getCustomerDetails(){
       manager1.getCustomerDetails();

}

public class DaoManager1{
  @Autowired
   private Service3 service3;
   @Autowired
   private Service4  service 4;

  public getCustomerDetails(){
    Service3.getCustName();
    Service4.getCustAddress();

}
```

My Question is how to mock DaoManager class?
If I mock it, I need to mock each and every manager/service which gets called from the getCustomerDetails method?
It looks like a big overhead for me. Any ideas or mebbe I am completely getting this wrong?

EDIT:

When I run my junit , i get following error.

Caused by: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mockDaoManager': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private x.y.z.Service2  x.y.z.Service2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [x.y.z.Service2] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Have to get the DaoManager contract in an Interface and mock this last

```
 Interface IDaoManager {
     CustomerDetail getCustomerDetails();
 }

 public class DaoManager implements IDaoManager
```

then follow nsanglar advises

```
 IDaoManager daoManagerMock = mock(IDaoManager.class);
 [...]
```

Of course you will so have to inject the dao using its interface, which is, anyway, a good practice

Comment: Yes and moreover dependency injection should be done through interfaces too, so you will also improve your architecture

Answer (score 1):

Actually you only have to mock the object's behaviour, so basically you define what you expect the object will be doing without having to think about its implementation. In your case, when mocking the DaoManager you could for example write in your test setup:

```
DaoManager daoManagerMock = mock(DaoManager .class);
when(daoManagerMock .getCustomerDetails()).thenReturn(...);
```

So to answer your question, you don't have to mock every service/manager your dao depends on.

Comment: I have updated the question with the error message I receive. Since the member level managers/service are autowired, it tries to find objects which won't be available as I have not defined them in the javaconfig(MockedManagerConfig) file which I have created. I have only added managers service which are called directly from DaoManager

Comment: Have you correctly mocked the DaoManager before? Before defining the expected behavior (when...thenReturn), you should do DaoManager daoMock = mock(DaoManager.class). I edited the example in my answer.